# Do you say "On the air" or "on air"?

Tags: phrase-usage, articles, prepositional-phrases

Which is more common, "on the air" or "on air"
The TV show was on air many years ago.

The TV show was on the air many years ago.

Comment: I would say that "on the air" is more common, although I don't think you would face any confusion using either.

Comment: on the air is more common for sure.

Comment: As a radio and electronics fan it always used to bother me that people think that radio waves need air to travel through.

Comment: I think "on the air" is more common for general use. "On air" might occur more as an adjective, e.g. "on-air comments".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes it's ridiculous. Everyone knows it's ether that's the medium. :)

Comment: Wow, it surprises me. I think "on air" is more common. I looked up the phrase in Longman dictionary and Oxford dictionary. They say "be on / off (the) air. The examples they give omit the word "the"                                                                                          eg. We'll be on air in three minutes.                                                                                         eg. We will be back on air tomorrow morning at 7.

Answer (score 4):

Webster's dictionary defines "[on **the** air](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20the%20air)" as an idiomatic term for broadcasting, and in the same entry notes that 'on air' is a "less common variant".

However, [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=live%20on%20air%2C%20live%20on%20the%20air&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clive%20on%20air%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clive%20on%20the%20air%3B%2Cc0) would suggest otherwise, with "live on air" being used far more than "live on *the* air".

This image is typical of the kind of sign you expect to see outside a radio or television studio. I searched for images of these and they were overwhelmingly "on air", with only the odd one saying "on *the* air", and those looked like mock-ups rather than real photographs.

[image: On-air sign]

Signage is usually abbreviated, so the fact they say "on air" doesn't mean that is the correct phrase. However, it may be that the abbreviation has come to be used more frequently. I have certainly heard both, and I don't believe either is incorrect. Personally, I would tend to use "on air" with reference to live broadcasting (eg "*the show is on air right now*") and "on the air" with reference to programming that is currently scheduled (eg "*the show has been on the air for ten years*", meaning it is still airing regularly, not constantly broadcasting that long).

Comment: I have the same intuition: "on air" seems specific to live broadcasting, while "on the air" could also refer to scheduled programming.